# Is there an equivalent to atexit() function for Jupyter python kernel?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm looking for a hook in jupyter, so I can pass a function to do cleanup work for me, specifically kill PID, when the jupyter kernel is stopped, restarted or shutdown.  I've tried atexit() function but it didn't work for me.  I've also tried iPython shutdown hook, it didn't work for me either.

Thanks.